# rock movement in AS3 basic shooter game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, game-physics

I need some help with some rock movement... I'm really new at this coding stuff and have pretty much no idea what i'm doing...

I have rocks moving every which way... What i want is them to start within a set boundary on the left and move to a set boundary on the right.

If they get hit I'd like them to explode rather then split into 2 more rocks. In the movie I have the multiple rocks (big, medium, small) and a frame called explode, but this script i tried to adapt from another code didn't seem to work in it..

```
    public function planeHit() {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,movePlane);
        MovieClip(parent).removePlane(this);
        gotoAndPlay("explode");
    }
```

When all bugs are gone (from being shot or leaving screen) I'd like a new wave to start...

Here's the script I have for the placement and movement of the rocks...

Any help you can give would be great!

```
    // ROCKS        

    // create a single rock of a specific size
    public function newRock(x,y:int, rockType:String) {

        // create appropriate new class
        var newRock:MovieClip;
        var rockRadius:Number;
        if (rockType == "Big") {
            newRock = new Rock_Big();
            rockRadius = 35;
        } else if (rockType == "Medium") {
            newRock = new Rock_Medium();
            rockRadius = 20;
        } else if (rockType == "Small") {
            newRock = new Rock_Small();
            rockRadius = 10;
        }


        // choose a random look
        newRock.gotoAndStop(Math.ceil(Math.random()*3+1));

        // set start position
        newRock.x = x;
        newRock.y = y;

        // set random movement and rotation

        var dx:Number = Math.random()*2.0;
        var dy:Number = Math.random()*2.0-1.0;

        // add to stage and to rocks list
        gameObjects.addChild(newRock);
        rocks.push({rock:newRock, dx:dx, dy:dy, rockType:rockType, rockRadius: rockRadius});
    }

    // create four rocks
    public function nextRockWave(event:TimerEvent) {
        rocks = new Array();
        newRock(100,100,"Big");
        newRock(200,100,"Big");
        newRock(450,100,"Big");
        newRock(350,100,"Big");
        gameMode = "play";
    }

    // animate all rocks
    public function moveRocks(timeDiff:uint) {
        for(var i:int=rocks.length-1;i>=0;i--) {

            // move the rocks
            var rockSpeed:Number = rockSpeedStart + rockSpeedIncrease*gameLevel;
            rocks[i].rock.x += rocks[i].dx*timeDiff*rockSpeed;
            rocks[i].rock.y += rocks[i].dy*timeDiff*rockSpeed;


            // wrap rocks
    if ((rocks[i].dx > 0) && (x <-50)) {
            gameObjects.removeChild;
            rocks.splice(); 
        }
            else if ((rocks[i].dx < 0) && (x > 350)) {
            gameObjects.removeChild;
            rocks.splice();         
        }


        }
    }

    public function rockHit(rockNum:uint) {
        // create two smaller rocks
        if (rocks[rockNum].rockType == "Big") {
            newRock(rocks[rockNum].rock.x,rocks[rockNum].rock.y,"Medium");
            newRock(rocks[rockNum].rock.x,rocks[rockNum].rock.y,"Medium");
        } else if (rocks[rockNum].rockType == "Medium") {
            newRock(rocks[rockNum].rock.x,rocks[rockNum].rock.y,"Small");
            newRock(rocks[rockNum].rock.x,rocks[rockNum].rock.y,"Small");
        }
        // remove original rock
        gameObjects.removeChild(rocks[rockNum].rock);
        rocks.splice(rockNum,1);
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?  Right now you just have a code dump and a wishlist of things to change.  Can you narrow it down to one thing you're struggling with?

Comment: Hey, sorry no problem. I like to change how the rocks move, I'd like them to move more in a straight line, but whatever I change they seem to move at random angles, I'm petty sure the Math.random controls this but I'm not sure how to change it to make them go in a straight line across the screen.                                                                                                       Secondly I'm not sure why when the rocks  move off the screen no more start, they just disappear and nothing happens, I don't even know what code would control that. Any help on this would be great

Answer (score 0):

To animate objects to move in a straight line using the code you posted, you have two options.

**1. Change the rock definition**

Change your rock generation code like this:

```
var dx:Number = Math.random()*2.0;
var dy:Number = 0;

// add to stage and to rocks list
gameObjects.addChild(newRock);
rocks.push({rock:newRock, dx:dx, dy:dy, rockType:rockType, rockRadius: rockRadius});
```

Then when you animate the rocks, you won't make any changes to the `y`-coordinate, so it'll stay on the same line as it moves.

**2.  Change your animation code**

Simply delete the line that animates the `y` value of the rocks:

```
// move the rocks
var rockSpeed:Number = rockSpeedStart + rockSpeedIncrease*gameLevel;
rocks[i].rock.x += rocks[i].dx*timeDiff*rockSpeed;

// wrap rocks
...
```

Then nothing in your loop is changing the `y`-coordinate, so they'll stay on the same line.

Comment: Hey this helps, and I worked out the issues with the random height!! YAY

Comment: Could you maybe help me with the boundaries I have under Wrap Rocks? I'm not sure why i'm not getting any new rocks after they go off screen...